# R: Visualizing the "path" taken by an optimization algorithm

Tags: r, function, animation, optimization, data-visualization

I am using R and trying to recreate the visualizations from this stackoveflow post, where the "path" taken by an optimization algorithm for some function is visualized:

[visualizing the optimization path till convergence in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797713/visualizing-the-optimization-path-till-convergence-in-r)

I created some fake data:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)


# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

Then, I defined the function:

```
  fitness <- function(x) {
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>%
        mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x[1] & b1 <= x[3], "a",
                            ifelse(a1 <= x[2] & b1 <= x[4], "b", "c")))
   
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
   
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
   
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
   
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
   
   
   
   
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
   
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[5],1,0 )))
                         
                         table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                                                  mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[6],1,0 )))
                                             
                                              table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                                                                       mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[7],1,0 )))
                                                                   
                            }                                       
                                                                   
                                                                   
                                                                   #group all tables
                                                                   
                                                                   final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
                                                                   # calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
                                                                   mean = mean(final_table$quant)
}
```

I then used an optimization algorithm on this function:

```
library(optimization)
Output <- optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)
```

**Problem** : Now, I am trying to follow the instructions from the previous stackoverflow post ([visualizing the optimization path till convergence in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797713/visualizing-the-optimization-path-till-convergence-in-r9)) to visualize the results of this algorithm:

First, define the grid:

```
library(gganimate)

#define grid

 l.grid <- 200
  grid.b <- as.matrix(expand.grid(b0=seq(-3,0.5,length.out=l.grid), b1=seq(-6,6,length.out=l.grid)))
  grid.f <-apply(grid.b,1,logll)
  grid.b <- as.data.frame(grid.b)
```

Next, visualize the results (e.g. between any 2 variables) - **But I am not sure how to adapt the code from the previous stackoverflow post to my example**:

```
#animate/visualize - not working

op <- sapply(
  seq_len( optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)$counts['function']), 
  function(i) { 
    set.seed(1234)
    optim([1], [2] , control = list(maxit = i))$par
  }
)
op_df <- data.frame(b0 = op[1,], b1 = op[2,])
op_df$step <- 1:nrow(op_df)

p <- ggplot(grid.b, aes(b0, b1)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = f)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = f), col = 'grey40') +
  geom_path(data = op_df, col = 'white') +
  geom_point(data = op_df, col = 'white') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)


library(gganimate)
a <- p + transition_reveal(step)
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just following along with this post, not the referenced, you create `grid.f` then don't subsequently use it.

Comment: @Chris : Thank you for your comment! I am still trying to adapt the code from this example .

Comment: It's [wicked slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797713/visualizing-the-optimization-path-till-convergence-in-r). What part you got working and what errors? You might want to reconsider your use of `cat` as variable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I made some changes to the optimization function.. I am still trying to change some new things and see if this fixes the problem. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Chris: Here are some updates I made : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324429/r-replacement-has-1-row-data-has-0