# Visualize optimization path of grid search for SVM classification parameter tuning

Tags: r, grid-search, e1071

I have done a classification using radial kernel svm of the `e1071` package and tried to tune the cost and gamma parameters with the `tune` function.

Here an example code with the `iris` data set:

```
data("iris", package = "datasets")

if (!require("e1071")) {install.packages("e1071")} else {library("e1071")}

Data <- list(Lab = as.character(iris[,5]),
             Mat = prcomp(iris[,-5])$x[,1:2])

set.seed(240319)

Data$svm.tune <- tune(svm, train.x = Data$Mat, train.y = as.factor(Data$Lab), 
                      ranges = list(cost = c(10**(-3:3)), 
                                    gamma = c(10**(-3:3))),
                      type = "C-classification", kernel = "radial", scale = FALSE,
                      tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "cross", cross = 5))

Data$svm.tune$Mat <- Data$svm.tune$performances[,-ncol(Data$svm.tune$performances)]
Data$svm.tune$Mat_2 <- xtabs(error~., data = Data$svm.tune$Mat)

par(pty = "m",
    mar = c(2,2,1,1),
    mgp = c(1,0,0),
    tck = -0.01, 
    cex.axis = 0.75, 
    font.main = 1)
image(x = log10(as.double(rownames(Data$svm.tune$Mat_2))),
      y = log10(as.double(colnames(Data$svm.tune$Mat_2))), 
      z = Data$svm.tune$Mat_2,
      col = viridis::inferno(50),
      xlab = expression(log[10](c)),
      ylab = expression(log[10](gamma)))
points(log10(Data$svm.tune$best.parameters$cost),
       log10(Data$svm.tune$best.parameters$gamma),
       pch = 19,
       col = "white")
dev.off()
```

resulting in the following graph:

[image: best results]

I marked the 'best' parameter combination with a white dot.

Is there a way to visualize the optimization path of a grid search, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797713/visualizing-the-optimization-path-till-convergence-in-r) (but without animation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the result I was looking for, but in case someone else has done a grid search and want to vizualise the path of the minima, you can calculate the minima of your error parameter for each grid parameter.

First, I calculated the value and the index of the respective minima:

```
min.val <- sapply(unique(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"cost"]), function(i) min(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"error"][Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"cost"] == i]))
min.idx <- sapply(unique(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"cost"]), function(i) which.min(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"error"][Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"cost"] == i]))
```

Then, I sorted the indices according to the minima values and vizualise the path with arrows:

```
par(pty = "m",
    mar = c(2,2,1,1),
    mgp = c(1,0,0),
    tck = -0.01, 
    cex.axis = 0.75, 
    font.main = 1)
image(x = log10(as.double(rownames(Data$svm.tune$Mat_2))),
      y = log10(as.double(colnames(Data$svm.tune$Mat_2))), 
      z = Data$svm.tune$Mat_2,
      col = viridis::inferno(50),
      xlab = expression(log[10](C)),
      ylab = expression(log[10](gamma)))
box()
for(i in seq_len(length(min.val) - 1))
{
  arrows(log10(unique(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"cost"]))[order(min.val, decreasing = TRUE)][i],
         log10(unique(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"gamma"]))[min.idx[order(min.val, decreasing = TRUE)]][i],
         log10(unique(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"cost"]))[order(min.val, decreasing = TRUE)][i + 1], 
         log10(unique(Data$svm.tune$Mat[,"gamma"]))[min.idx[order(min.val, decreasing = TRUE)]][i + 1],
         length = 0.05, 
         angle = 30,
         code = 2,
         lwd = 1.5,
         col = "white")
}
dev.off()
```

resulting in the following graph:
[image: optimization path]